# Does WinRT have a storage option that persists even after uninstalling the application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to put some files and folders in a place that my WinRT application could access and read files from. These files and folders must be locked and permanent even when I uninstall the application.

Comment: use the above http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 main categories of folders that you have access to from a Windows Store Application:

- `/AppData/Local/<yourpackage>`
- Standard available libraries (Music, Pictures, Videos)
- Libraries that require elevated permissions (Documents)
- User-defined folders (through a `FilePicker`)

Typically you will store data specific to your application in the first kind and data for the user in a library or a user-defined folder.

When your application is uninstalled, its package folder under `/AppData/Local` is removed so there is nothing left there (note that this contains the directories which you get using `ApplicationData.Current.Local` and `ApplicationData.Current.Roaming`).

Therefore in order to save data persistent through installations you will have to save them in a different directory. Note however that in the case of option 4, the user might not decide to give you access to the folder he picked out the previous time or that he doesn't want to give the application access to the Documents library.

I think a more solid solution would be to save the data on a remote location so that the user can download it when he installs the application again, rather than relying on everything being saved at the user's device.

With regards to the locking: you could look into the [`DataProtectionProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.aspx) and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: thanks joroen Vannevel for replay. the main problem is i dont want to user to see this files or to remove them so i want to put this files in location that just my application can access them and also this file dont remove even the application is uninstalled

Comment: Then you should encrypt the bytes and decrypt them inside your application. That will make the file unusable unless it's used through your app

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate Jeroen's response:

- To save data locally in a place that won't be deleted when the app is uninstalled, you must use the file picker to have the user choose a location.
- Saving the data remotely is the only option that doesn't require user interaction.
- It's possible to save data in the app's roaming settings, as those are retained for some period of time after the app is uninstalled. If the user has the app installed elsewhere, that data will be retained continuously. If there are no other installations, it will be retained for around a month.

I recently wrote a blog post addressing this exact scenario in more detail, including how to get a persistent user identity for any data your store remotely: http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2014/07/31/persisting-data-after-uninstall/.